# How can I make responsive vertical menu that shrinks when screen's width is less than 800px?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, menu

I want to make responsive vertical menu with icons, that would shrink with transition (fade in to left) when screen width is to small. It would look like this - normal menu:

- (icon1) Position1
- (icon2) Position2
- (icon3) Position3

and after shrinking window to let's say 800px it should fade into the left and look like this:

- (icon1)
- (icon2)
- (icon3)

How do I make such thing using only HTML and CSS?

Comment: The short answer is use CSS media queries: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp


A popular example is Bootstrap's Navbar: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/

Comment: What is "Position 1," "Position 2," and "Position 3" supposed to indicate? What do you mean by "*it should fade into the left*"? What is "it," and it should fade in what way? A gradient? A transition? Can you share a picture of what the initial menu should look like, and the smaller menu? Can you show your (attempted, relevant) "*[mcve]*" code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To make the element fade out when the page width gets smaller than 800px, for screensizes bigger than 800px, you need to give the list items a position of relative, set the list items left property to 0 and opacity to 1  so that they'll be displayed normally, and for screensizes smaller than 800px, change the left value to 100% and opacity to 0 so that it'll not be displayed anymore. next set its transition property for all screen sizes to 'all 1s ease-in-out' so the sliding will be smooth.

> for the icon and the item to be displayed on the same line, just set the display of the li containing the item and the icon to flex and their align-items property to center so they'll be horizontally aligned.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .hide-800 {
    left: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .hide-800 {
    left: 5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
}

.list {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class='list'>
    <li class="row">
      <span class="icon">icon1</span>
      <div class="item hide-800">item1</div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
      <span class="icon">icon2</span>
      <div class="item hide-800">item2</div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
      <span class="icon">icon3</span>
      <div class="item hide-800">item3</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank You, I found that help really useful. I am still struggling with 2 more things: I want to position text just next to the icons, not below them. And second thing - how can I make smooth transition so that when the items hide, they slide smoothly to the left and disapear.

Comment: I answered my own question with code I made. Not quite sure how to reply to Your comment with code.

Comment: just edited the answer, now if you change the browser width, when the screen size gets bigger than 800 the items will slide in and when it gets smaller than 800px the items slide out and fade.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    text-decoration: none;
}
body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
  img{
    width: 2em;
  }
  .content{
    float: left;
    border: 5px solid red;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left:10px;
  }


a{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
  .navbar {
  width: 15%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar a {
  float: NONE;
  display: block;;
  padding: 12px;
  color: rgb(125, 137, 240);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(37, 179, 171);
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
    .hide-800 {
      display: none;
    }
    .content{
        width: 85%;
    }
    .navbar {
        width: 10%;
        overflow: auto;
      }
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="image"> <a href="#"><img src="icons/home.png">  <div class="hide-800">DASHBOARD</div> </a> </div>
        <a href="#"><img src="icons/files.png"> <div class="hide-800">E-PRESCRIPTIONS</div></a> 
        <a href="#"><img src="icons/profile-user.png"> <div class="hide-800">MY PATIENTS</div></a> 
        <a href="#"><img src="icons/send.png"> <div class="hide-800">INVITE</div></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="icons/profile-user.png"> <div class="hide-800">MY PROFILE</div></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="icons/settings.png"><div class="hide-800">SETTINGS</div></a></a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum aliquet at neque nec maximus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Pellentesque condimentum pellentesque faucibus. Phasellus lobortis nisi sollicitudin arcu hendrerit interdum. Nulla semper tellus at dignissim rhoncus. Phasellus laoreet semper metus, eget aliquet urna mattis in. Etiam laoreet ut purus suscipit pharetra. Aliquam rutrum, risus vitae egestas ultricies, ligula lorem lobortis arcu, at dignissim felis mauris vitae lorem. Vivamus urna libero, facilisis nec tincidunt eu, ultricies eu arcu. Sed id aliquet lorem, eu egestas arcu. Cras cursus vulputate felis nec facilisis. Nunc et arcu rhoncus, fermentum lectus eu, sagittis velit. Curabitur nisi dui, semper nec felis sed, tempor blandit neque. Cras varius aliquet diam in maximus. Proin ultricies, sem eget lacinia lobortis, mauris quam venenatis neque, a rhoncus metus odio vel diam.</div>
  </body>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).